# Update jquerymobile header in multipage layout

Tags: jquery-mobile, header, multipage

I have a multi-page layout document where each all pages have the same header:

How can I update all pages at once with a certain text after the page has loaded?

Comment: Single file or multi HTML files?

Comment: single file, only change the header

Comment: can you post your code?

Comment: I one file with several pages on it like this:

<div data-role="page" id="page1">
 <div data-role="header" data-theme="b"  data-id="head1" data-position="fixed" >
 </div>
 <div data-role="content">
 </div>
 <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed" data-theme="a"  data-id="foot1" >
   <div data-role="navbar">
   <ul>
     <li></li>
     <li></li>
     <li></li>
   </ul>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>

Comment: ok check this http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/UM5xa/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below code will replace old header of all pages with a new header. All you need is to specify when you want to do this? `pageshow`, `pagebeforeshow`, `pagehide`, `pagebeforehide`, etc...

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/UM5xa/)**

```
var header = '<div data-role=header><h1>new header</h1></div>';

$('[data-role=page]').each(function () {
 $(this).find('[data-role=header]').replaceWith(header);
 $('[data-role=page]').trigger('pagecreate');
});
```

Comment: This works great for one page (the page the user is on), but it does not update all other pages - this is a multipage layout.